# swipe gesture and uisegmented control

Tags: iphone, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uisegmentedcontrol

In the notification center (iOS 7) it is possible to swipe between the "Today", "All", and "Missed" options of (what I presume is ) a segmented control.  I would like to do this in my code but am unsure how to contiunue.  I have a uisegmented control and a uitableviiew as my view.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by following the respective steps:

1. Add 2 swipe gesture recognisers(one to swipe left and the other to
   swipe right)
2. For each of them on the connections inspector reference the outlet
       collection as your main view.
3. Selecting actions when swiping as follows:
4. viewSelector is the UISegmentedControl and firstView, secondView and
       thirdView are 3 views used to select which one is being shown.

Code:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        firstView.hidden = false
        secondView.hidden = true
        thirdView.hidden = true
    case 1:
        firstView.hidden = true
        secondView.hidden = false
        thirdView.hidden = true
    case 2:
        firstView.hidden = true
        secondView.hidden = true
        thirdView.hidden = false
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@IBAction func swipeLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = (viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex + 1) % viewSelector.numberOfSegments
    indexChanged(viewSelector)
}

@IBAction func swipeRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = (viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex - 1) % viewSelector.numberOfSegments
    if(viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == -1){
        viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = viewSelector.numberOfSegments-1
    }
    println(viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex)
    indexChanged(viewSelector)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished using a UIScrollView with paging enabled, and when the user scrolls through the pages, the UISegmentedControl's selectedSegmentIndex is updated.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it isn't a scrollView with paging enabled to me. I think it could be easier with a UIGestureRecognizer. If it recognises a gesture, slide the view of the current tab and update the segmented control.